# return same view with last state and validation error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

Call Controller Method With Model And Check If Model Is Valid If Model Not Valid Return Validation Error, Condition Calling Controller Method From Some View Which Is In Some Other Controller Please Check Complete Code

[This Is Welcom.cshtml Page From Where I Am Calling The Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ary1q.png)

[This is Application Setting Controller If The Model Is Valid I Had Perform The Logic And Redirect To new Page According To Success Or Fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsNpc.png)

Comment: I cant enter code properly so upload pic please check pick

Comment: As MVC basic application you must see registration page if password not full fill password policy it return error from server
this register method and view register is same and both return view one is call on get method and other on post method

Comment: but in my case i have different view and different method name
and if i return view from application setting controller and update application parameter method it return to updateapplicationparemeter view which is not exist

Comment: I suggest re-wording your question text as this is quite confusing. Not really sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Code needs to be in the question (not links to images of it)